# What is the correct way to access the Room database?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-jetpack

I hope you can help me.

I am new working with Android Jetpack, specific with Room component. As they mention in the documentation, acceding the database in the main thread is a bad practice, so I was wonder how we access to the database. We need to create a "Worker" and a "WorkRequest" and then enqueue in a background thread with WorkManager? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You shouldn't be using WorkManager for this.  WorkManager is for deferrable work, which this almost certainly isn't if it's to display UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WorkManager` is not the right way to access `Room` database. The reason is that:

> `WorkManager` is intended to be used to run **deferrable**,
>   guaranteed background asynchronous work when the work’s
>   **constraints** are satisfied

So, there are a couple of `WorkManager` treats that you don't match with accessing `Room` database or any database generally speaking:

- First: You need instant access to the database, but `WorkManager`
  is deferable.
- Second: In most cases you need to access Room database with no constraints, but `WorkManager` runs when constraints are satisfied.

Instead, there are other ways, like [`Thread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread), [`Executors`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors), [Kotlin Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines), and also [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) provides asynchronous access to database queries.

Have a look at other documentation links: [Concurrent](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) and [Threading](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads)

Comment: If I just want to make a simple insert into the database. What do you think is the best way? According with this [Processes and threads overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads) could be using threads, because AsyncTask is for bigger jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new Thread to run Room queries.

If you are using Kotlin, then Coroutines will be your best choice for multithreading
I suggest you to follow this course in [google code lab.](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-coroutines-and-room/#0)

You can use also RxJava for multithreading if you are familiar with reactive programming.